# clearing float effect without using clear div

Tags: html, css, css-float

i know adding clear div after every float makes the code dirty.

Here is the code

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="left-block">
                <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-block">
                <a href="#" class="login"></a>
                <a href="#" class="register"></a>
                <div class="technique"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
             <div class="content-title"><h1>Умная Помощница</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.left-block {float:left;}
.right-block{float:right;}
```

left and right block have floats(aligned to left and right). I need to clear the float effect after them, so #content is displayed right. How can i do that without using clear div?

Thanks

Comment: `#content { clear: both }`

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) ([2](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/))

e.g,.

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the existing `<div id="content">` a clearing css attribute:

```
#content{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of clearfix hacks and techniques.  One of the easiest is to just add `overflow: hidden` to the container `#header` div.

My preferred method is **[Nicholas Gallagher's "Micro Clearfix"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)**:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1; /* IE6/7 only */
}
```

Add the `cf` class to your `#header` element and you'll be all set!

You can also clear floats with the `clear: left|right|both` property which means the element will wrap after any floated elements on that side (or both sides) - in your case adding `clear: both` to `#content` would work too, but a clearfix solution is preferable because simply adding `clear: both` will solve your float positioning issue for `#content` but will not force `#header` to contain the two floated elements inside it.